# SQLAlchemy raises None, causes TypeError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using the declarative extension in SQLAlchemy, and I noticed a strange error when I attempted to save an instance of a mapped class with incorrect data (specifically a column declared with nullable=False with a value of None).

The class (simplified):

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    userid = Column(String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Causing the error (session is a SQLAlchemy session):

```
>>> u = User()
>>> session.add(u)
>>> session.commit()

...

TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType
```

Looking at the code that causes this exception, I found (in sqlalchemy.orm.session):

```
except:
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
    raise
```

The exception being caught in this case is a sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError. If I change these lines to:

```
except Exception as e:
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
    raise e
```

then the problem goes away, and the OperationalError gets thrown instead of None. Shouldn't the original code work in any recent version of Python though? (I'm using 2.7.2) Is this error somehow specific to my application?

Python 2.7.2

SQLAlchemy 0.7.5

UPDATE: the error seems to be specific to my application in some way. I'm wrapping an eventlet.db_pool with a SQLAlchemy engine, which appears to be the source of the problem somehow. Running my simple test with either in-memory SQLite or basic MySQL engine doesn't have this problem, but with the db_pool it does.

Test case: https://gist.github.com/1980584

The full traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_case_9525220.py", line 41, in <module>
    session.commit()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 645, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 313, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 297, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1547, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1635, in _flush
    raise
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not NoneType
```

Comment: What version of sqlalchemy are you using?

Comment: what DBAPI is this (including version) and what is the exact nature of the error ?   OperationalError is propagated from the DBAPI.  A full reproducing test here would be best and attach it as a ticket to http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/newticket

Comment: I agree that your first block of code should work fine in any version of Python that I've used.  I'm currently using 2.6.5 and I wrote a little dummy app to test (note: NOT using SQLAlchemy).  I created a custom exception and raised it.  I caught it just the way the first code block does and raised again.  The correct exception got raise for me.  I'm looking forward to seeing what you discover because this makes no sense to me.

Comment: Can you post a full traceback?

Comment: Added the full traceback. Sorry about the delay - SO's favorites/notifications seem to have stopped working for me, so I only find out about comments when I visit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what I've discovered:

- The exception (an `OperationalError`) is ok until the failed transaction rolls back (in `Session._flush()`).
- The transaction rollback is handled by mysqldb through `eventlet.tpool`.  Specifically, `eventlet.tpool.execute` is called, which involves creating an `eventlet.Event` and calling its `wait` method.
- While waiting, a few complicated thread-related things happen, one of is checking for an exception and passing it to the Event to handle.  It picks up the `OperationalError` which is still in `sys.exc_type`, and ultimately clears it in `eventlet.event.hubs.hub.BaseHub.switch`.
- Control returns to `Session._flush`, and the exception is re-raised (using `raise`), but at this point there is no exception so it tries to `raise None`.

This behaviour can be reproduced with a simple example:

```
from eventlet import tpool

def m(): 
    pass

try:
    raise TypeError
except:
    tpool.execute(m)
    raise
```

Its a bit unclear exactly what eventlet should be doing in this situation, so I don't know whether the bug should be reported to sqlalchemy or eventlet, or both.

The easiest way to rectify it is, as you've already noted, to change the last few lines of `sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session._flush` from

```
    except Exception:
        transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
        raise
```

to

```
    except Exception, e:
        transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
        raise e
```

**Edit:**  I have raised an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/eventlet/eventlet/issue/118/exceptions-are-cleared-during) on eventlet's issue tracker.  It might be worth raising it on sqlalchemy too though.

Comment: Nice work - now it makes sense. My fix worked because it recorded the exception, before eventlet cleared it in the rollback, then raised it explicitly. I'll try raising an issue on sqlalchemy when I get a chance.